# Defining a function and immediately call it in Coffee, can't get the desired result

Tags: coffeescript

Can't get my Coffee script to compile **exactly into**:

```
( function (root) { return 'Hello Coffee'; }(this) );
```

First attempt:

```
do (root) ->
    'Hello Coffee'
```

... is not generating the same code as above, outputting (with `--bare`):

```
(function(root) {
  return 'Hello Coffee';
})(root);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no reason to believe that you can get exactly that JavaScript and there's probably no reason to get exactly that JavaScript. You can get something functionally equivalent though:

```
((root) -> 'Hello Coffee')(@)
```

becomes this JavaScript:

```
(function(root) { return 'Hello Coffee'; })(this);
```

which does the same thing as your JavaScript.

---

The [`do` keyword](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) is meant for use inside loops:

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

You'd normally use `do` in things like this:

```
for x in a
    do (x) ->
        $("##{x}").click -> console.log x
```

where you want to break the connection between a loop variable and its use in a closure. That's why `root` shows up twice in the JavaScript version of

```
do (root) ->
    'Hello Coffee'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this

```
do (root = @) ->
  'Hello Coffee'
```

This code will be compiled into

```
(function(root) {
  return 'Hello Coffee';
})(this);
```

Please, see [CoffeeScript.org console example](http://coffeescript.org/#try:do%20(root%20%3D%20%40)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%22Hello%20Coffee%22)